# Why is a C++ bool var true by default?

Tags: c++, static, boolean, default

bool "bar" is by default true, but it should be false, it can not be initiliazied in the constructor. is there a way to init it as false without making it static?

*Simplified version of the code:*

**foo.h**

```
class Foo{
 public:
     void Foo();
private:
     bool bar;
}
```

**foo.c**

```
Foo::Foo()
{  
   if(bar)
   {
     doSomethink();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: because the constructor can be called more than one time, I may not change that routine because that would lack a bigger peace of software:(

Comment: How would the constructor ever be called more than once?

Comment: From the code, it looks like it might be a persistent variable which controls how the objects are constructed - in which case it needs to be `static`. As it is, it's not initialised at all, so it could have either value.

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about what you're really trying to accomplish for anybody to give really sensible advice about this.

Comment: Sounds like he's updating an existing system which is probably undocumented and probably quite complex. And it's also possible he may not have enough knowledge about this system to paint a detailed picture.

Comment: The name of the method doSomethink() most certainly contains a typo. You probably meant doSomethinking(), methinks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**In fact, by default it's not initialized at all.** The value you see is simply some trash values in the memory that have been used for allocation.

If you want to set a default value, you'll have to ask for it in the constructor :

```
class Foo{
 public:
     Foo() : bar() {} // default bool value == false 
     // OR to be clear:
     Foo() : bar( false ) {} 

     void foo();
private:
     bool bar;
}
```

UPDATE C++11:

If you can use a C++11 compiler, you can now default construct instead (most of the time):

```
class Foo{
 public:
     // The constructor will be generated automatically, except if you need to write it yourself.
     void foo();
private:
     bool bar = false; // Always false by default at construction, except if you change it manually in a constructor's initializer list.
}
```

Comment: and therefore you have a almost 100% chance of `if (bar)` being true.

Comment: some compilers will initialize the memory in debug builds to a specific pattern.  If using one of those compilers, debug builds WILL have 100% chance of bar being true.

Comment: IIRC Darwin initialises memory to zero by default, so you can also end up with what appears to be inconsistent behaviour across platforms.

Comment: @Adam: The language does not mandate any specific physical representation of `false` and `true`, which means that in theory an implementation can use, say, physical `1` for `true` and all other physical patterns for `false`. On such an implementation an unitialized `bool` object will amost always be `false`.

Comment: What are you (other commenters) talking about ? Both constructors from Klaim's code are correct. (I suspect you are unaware of the zero-initialization done in the first constructor -> see n3000 §8.5/5 /7 and /10)

Comment: @Luc: The comments aren't about Klaim's code but are about the repercussions of the first sentence in his answer (trying to show how the sentence results in the behavior that the questioner is seeing given the code in his question).

Comment: @AndreyT: +1 - you're dead on right. However, I was talking from my [Obj]C[++] experience, where it's just 0/1 the 'normal' way around :)

Comment: Just to add compiler's experience: VC2003 initialize booleans to false in debug mode, gcc 3.4.2 let garbage... made for quite a bug for me over a year ago because of a library I used :/

Comment: @Matthieu - In think that depends on what you mean by "debug mode".  My notes say that for a debug build VC will use /GZ to set memory to 0xcd or 0xcc (depending on it's a heap allocation or local) so an uninitialized bool would eval to `true`. I'd like to know if my notes are wrong (ideally without having to dig up a VC2003 install). My notes also say that VC versions 2005 or newer will use /RTC1 option by default in a Debug project to actively check at compile and runtime whether or not the variable is initialized, making it even more difficult to accidentally use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Doesn't the standard say anywhere that an uninitialized bool might be *neither* true nor false?

Comment: @UncleBens: yes, in a footnote the standard says, "Using a bool value in ways described by this International Standard as ‘undefined,’ such as by examining the value of an uninitialized
automatic variable, might cause it to behave as if it is neither true nor false". As always, undefined behavior means all bets are off...

Comment: @AdamWoś when full optimization is enabled you may end up with `if(bar){/*no hit*/} else if(!bar){/*no hit*/} else {/*hit*/}`

Comment: (re other commenters/readers) there's a big difference between a one-off initialisation of the "uninitialised" data segment, stack or e.g. `sbrk`-provided heap and having those regions continually overwritten with specific values with every release/reuse of memory, such that the OPs code would be consistently `true` or `false`.  *very* few systems would have such consistency.

Answer (score 5):

Klaim's answer is spot on. To "solve" your problem you could use a [constructor initialization list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/). I strongly suggest you read that page as it may clear up some similar queries you may have in future.

Answer (score 2):

C / C++ don't initialize variables for you at all.  The memory location which is now in use by bar had a value in it which is interpreted as "true".  This will not always be the case.  You must initialize it in your constructor.

Comment: It depends.  POD member variables aren't initialized, but non-POD members get default constructed.  And, of course, global/static variables are initialized.

Answer (score 2):

This program has undefined behavior. Intrinsic types do not have constructors. You could do `bool bar = bool();` but it's better to define the actual value in your foo class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Foo
{ 
  public: 
    void Foo(); 
  private: 
     bool bar; 
} 

Foo::Foo() : bar(false)
{
  if(bar) 
  { 
    doSomething(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, @Klaim beat me to providing an example.

Comment: foo() is a typo, foo() should be Foo()

Comment: After OP updated question, foo() no longer exists, so I reverted, @Nick.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the value of bar in the ctor, I assume you're trying to set it before the object is created?  I think you meant to make it a static class variable instead of an instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize any variable when you declare it.

```
bool bar = 0;
```

Comment: i thougt that same, but i get an C2864 error then:
only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

Comment: This is true for local variables, but not class members.

Comment: `0` is an integer literal. `false` is a boolean literal.