# boolean variable has value without initialization?

Tags: c++, boolean, ifstream

I have the following code snippet:

```
ifstream input(aFileName);

bool select;
while (!input.eof())
{
    input >> select;
    cout << select << endl;
    if(select){
    // do something
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I discover the following two things that I do not understand:

The variable `select` has value 1 right after execution of the line `bool select;` i.e. apparently *without initialization*. How can this be?

Please let me know if the provided information is sufficient. I can of course adapt this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a C++ bool var true by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043823/why-is-a-c-bool-var-true-by-default)

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with Boolean you should always store a default value when you initialize the variable. Here is someone from stack overflow explaining what effects might occur if there was no default value: [Default value of an unset boolean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863956/default-value-of-an-unset-boolean-in-c)

Therefore, if you want to start the value at false then make sure you initialize it at a false value.

**C++**

```
ifstream input(aFileName);

bool select = false; // DEFAULT
while (!input.eof())
{
    input >> select;
    cout << select << endl;
    if(select){
    // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link!

Comment: Not a problem, buddy. You could mark as answered, it helps me out and helps others view this answer if they are stuck on it as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The value of an uninitialized scalar variable defined at block scope is garbage.

`1` is just as valid as any other garbage value.

Comment: @Svalbard: The two parts of your question are unrelated. You might want to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about point 2, but for point 1: variables in C/C++ that aren't initialised can have *any* value. You should not depend on the value of an uninitialised variable.