# When I call a function with single argument of type bool with empty parentheses, what is the value of a bool parameter?

Tags: function, c++11, boolean, arguments, parameter-passing

I just wonder what is the value of bool parameter of member function, when function is called without passing value?
Is it false? Why is it false?

```
bool CSVread::Reset( bool partial_reset /* = false */ )
```

then reset is called as

```
obj.reset()
```

No argument is passed so what is value of partial_reset and why?   In visual studio it is false, but why?

I cannot find any definition of bool value as being false for function argument?
Isn't function argument part of function scope, so it should be of automatic storage and thus its default value is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

By default it is not initialized so it could be true or false depending on the trash values in memory.

See this answer for more info : [Why is a C++ bool var true by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043823/why-is-a-c-bool-var-true-by-default)

BTW it is not a good practice to use function that accepts arguments without giving them or a default value. This should lead to a compilation error unless you have lazy compiler options

Comment: i saw this link before writing my question but it did not talk about case of empty parentheses

Comment: in visual studio it is false

Answer (score 0):

Every bool is false by default unless you change it to another value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values