# Is this the best way to check if a number is prime in c++

Tags: c++

Was trying to do RSA encryption, so im trying to get p and q. So I need to check if they are prime numbers. Is this how to do it, is there a faster more efficient way for bigger numbers? thanks!

```
bool checkIsPrime(int x) {
    bool isPrime;
    int i;
    // 0 and 1 are not prime numbers
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
        isPrime = false;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 2; i <= x / 2; ++i) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        cout << x << " is a prime number";
    }
    else {
        cout << x << " is not a prime number";
    }
}
```

Comment: A trivial improvement would be to go till `sqrt(x)` instead of `x / 2`, but there are many more improvements that can be made. This is a highly active area of research.

Comment: The answer is yes, there are better solutions. Search "primality testing" and you'll get all sorts of hits; you're not going to independently invent a useful primality testing algorithm that's usable at the sizes required for RSA. Or just use GMP (or better, an actual crypto library) and it'll give you the APIs to do this properly directly.

Comment: For determining if a number is prime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test (it even has pseudocode)    Also, `int` only goes to 2 billion which means quite small numbers compared to the numbers you would normally use for encryption.

Comment: What hardware is it running on?

Comment: Just my computer for now, doing uni research

Comment: Unrelated for the most part, but you should initialise `isPrime`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043823/why-is-a-c-bool-var-true-by-default) for a better explanation, but basically your `if (isPrime)` is passing because it's _likely_ to hold a garbage value which evaluates to `true` if uninitialised, but not guaranteed.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi, an intel-based x86 system, perhaps an amd-based x86 system? Such things make a difference when you want to push the system to the limits. ;)

Comment: Since no even number above `2` is prime, you could factor that into it